# Paradox: Summation of natural logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, infinite-product, paradoxes

Consider the expression : $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(i+2)-\ln(i+4)$$

If one evaluates it out, one gets $$\ln(\frac{3\times4\times5\times6\times...}{5\times6\times7\times8\times...})=\ln(12)$$  That value is positive.

However, each individual term of the original expression is negative, so the sum should be negative.

What's going on there?

Comment: What you do by canceling out this infinite product is to effectively splitting up the series $\sum_i \ln(i+2) - \ln(i+4)$ into $\sum_i \ln(i+2)$ and $\sum_i \ln(i+4)$, index shift one of them, and substract the resulting series. But the series $\sum_i \ln(i+2)$ and $\sum_i \ln(i+4)$ diverge to $\infty$, so this approach leads to the wrong result of $\ln(12)$. Just as infinite sums cannot always be reordered you can’t just reorder and cancel infinite fractions.

Comment: This reminds me of that old paradox:$$1=0+1=0+0+1=0+0+0+1=\dotsb=0+0+\dotsb=0$$

Comment: This phenomenon has nothing to do with logarithms and can be exhibited much more simply as follows: consider $\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdots$.  Everything but the $2$ cancels, so the result should be $2$... but every term in the product is less than $1$, so the result must also be less than $1$!

Comment: Well, it appears this this is one of those divergent summations that have an analytic continuation or something.  In fact, trying to solve an infinite summation that **diverges** using methods designed for infinite summations that **converge**, as you have done, produces these interesting "paradoxes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \ln(i+2)-\ln(i+4)$$
is a [Telescoping serie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) in fact you can highlight the terms that cancel out by expanding the serie
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \ln(i+2)-\ln(i+4) = \ln(3)-\ln(5)+\ln(4)-\ln(6)+\ln(5)-\ln(7)+\ldots \\ = \ln(3)+\ln(4) - \infty = \ln(12) - \infty = -\infty$$
so actually there is not any paradox.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if we ever truncate the sum, we do get a negative number. The first few partial sums are thus

\begin{align}
\ln{\frac{3\cdot4}{5\cdot6}}&=\ln{\frac{12}{30}}\\ \\
\ln{\frac{3\cdot4\cdot5}{5\cdot6\cdot7}}&=\ln{\frac{12}{42}}\\ \\
\ln{\frac{3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot 6}{5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot 8}}&=\ln{\frac{12}{56}}\\ \\
\end{align}

What you have done is counted extra terms which contribute to the numerator, but not the terms which contribute to the denominator.

By the same logic, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k-(k+1)=1-2+2-3+3-4+\cdots=1$. But clearly this sum diverges since you are always adding $-1$.

Comment: Indeed, if the first $H$ terms are added, you get $\ln\frac{12}{(H+3)(H+4)}$, which becomes $\ln\frac{12}\infty=-\infty$ as $H\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the phrase "if one evaluates it out." The series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \ln(i+2)-\ln(i+4)$ diverges, as we can see by comparing it to the series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln(\frac{1}{i})$.

Answer (score 0):

*Probably too complex as an answer but too long for a comment.*

Let us consider $$S_a=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(i+a)$$ Using Pochhamer notation, it writes $$S_a=\log \left((a+1)_n\right)$$ Using instead the gamma function, it writes $$S_a=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (a+n+1)}{\Gamma (a+1)}\right)$$ Now, using Stirling approximation for the gamma function when $n$ is large $$S_a=n (\log (n)-1)+\left(\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (n)+\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{2 \pi }}{\Gamma
   (a+1)}\right)\right)+\frac{6 a^2+6
   a+1}{12 n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}\right)$$ which makes $$S_a-S_b=(a-b) \log (n)+\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (b+1)}{\Gamma (a+1)}\right)+\frac{(a-b) (a+b+1)}{2 n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}\right)$$

Comment: Definitely too long as a comment.

Comment: @SimpleArt. Is it a positive or negative comment ?

Comment: I don't quite know.  I personally like it, but some may think it too confusing.